# Problems loading the Lotro Store. It doesn't load

Tags: 14.04, wine

First of all... I'm not new to Linux, but I'm certainly not an advanced user.

I've been playing LOTRO on Linux for ages, with the help of wine, and this problem never existed before. The LOTRO Store doesn't load. The LOTRO Store page on the game is just blank.

Does someone have any thoughts about how solving it?